# how to create a package in swagger code gen tool in addition to the api and model package

Tags: c#, rest, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I am learning to use swagger code gen to generate a bunch of csharp files from swagger.json file.

In the CSharpClientCodeGen.class , I noticed there are variables for apiPackage and modelPackage that generates the Api and Model cs files in them. I would like to create a new package similar to apiPackage and modelPackage.

I tried adding in the following code

```
public class csharpcodegen extends CSharpClientCodeGen
{
protected String newPackage="IO.Swagger.New";

}
```

And then built the client code, but I dont see the new package folder in there.

Not sure how to do this. It would be great if you can point me to resources on how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to customize the package name, you can pass a config file (e.g. config.json) to the [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen). Here is a full list of configuration option available for C# code generator:

```
swagger-codegen|master⚡ ⇒ java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar config-help -l csharp

CONFIG OPTIONS
    packageName
        C# package name (convention: Camel.Case), default: IO.Swagger

    packageVersion
        C# package version, default: 1.0.0
```

For example, to generate C# SDK, prepare the config file as follows

```
{
  "packageName": "Com.RestUnited",
}
```

Then run the following command:

```
  java -jar modules/swagger-codegen-cli/target/swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate \
  -i /var/tmp/swagger_spec.yaml \
  -l csharp \
  -o /var/tmp/csharp/test/ \
  -c /var/tmp/csharp.json
```

To request for new option on customizing the C# SDK, please submit via the Github [page](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues)

Comment: Where did you get the language option from? I don't see it listed anywhere in the project documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that helps. It would be nice if they listed the supported client languages and frameworks somewhere other than the command line help. I had to dig into their repo to find out that they generate csharp using the RestSharp framework.